# Series expansion from the red book on special functions by Richard Askey

Tags: series-expansion

I want to check my calculations via mathematica.

In the book I am reading there's this expansion:
$$\frac{(1+\frac{1}{j})^x}{1+x/j}=1+\frac{x(x-1)}{2j^2}+\mathcal{O}(1/j^3)$$

though I get instead of the term $\frac{x(x-1)}{2j^2}$ in the rhs the term: $-\frac{x(x+1)}{2j^2}$.

So I want to check by mathematica if my calculations are correct, how do you suggest me to implement it in mathematica?

Thanks!

Comment: `Series[(1 + 1/j)^x/(1 + x/j), {j, Infinity, 2}]` results in $$1+\frac{(x-1) x}{2 j^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^3\right) .$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "prepare" expression for Taylor expansion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241057/how-to-prepare-expression-for-taylor-expansion) IMO this method is better to use as it is fully self-contained and does not run the risk of any unforeseen errors occurring from the use of `ReplaceAll` to perform substitutions, but YMMV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the `Series` functionality: `Series[f[z], {z, c, n}]` expands `f[z]` in `z` around `c` to order `n`. Here we want to expand in `1/j`, so we'll make a new variable `jinv` ($j$-inverse) to represent `1/j`, and write our function in terms of that. We then want to expand around `jinv = 0` to order `2`.

So, we get

```
Series[(1 + jinv)^x/(1 + x jinv), {jinv, 0, 2}]
```

which returns

```
1  +  1/2 (-1+x) x jinv^2  +  O[jinv]^3
```

So, unfortunately(?), it looks like the book is right.

This is how I think of expanding around a “composite variable” like $1/j$, but as @user64494 points out, you can also expand around $j$ directly in this case, by expanding around $j=\infty$!

```
Series[(1 + 1/j)^x/(1 + x/j), {j, Infinity, 2}]
```

which gives the same answer under interpreting `jinv` as `1/j`.

To see why, you could possibly use Wolfram Alpha's step-by-step solution from within Mathematica!

```
WolframAlpha["D[(1 + w)^x/(1 + x w), {w, 2}]", IncludePods -> "Input", 
 AppearanceElements -> {"Pods"}, PodStates -> {"Input__Show steps"}]
```

(Here `w = jinv`, and we'd be substituting `w = 0` at the end to get `1/2 (-1+x) x`.)

Comment: Ok, I think I see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: wait a minute, if you plug in $w=0$ you get zero. I just plugged the script your wrote (the one last of code), and we get:$\frac{w (x-1) x (w+1)^{x-1}}{(w x+1)^2}$, which when we plug $w=0$ vanishes, am I wrong here?

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have been the second derivative!

Comment: The coefficient of $1/j$ is, in fact, 0, so that's consistent with the book. Fixing the answer now...

Comment: thorimur, it might be helpful if you update your answer to show the full breadth of functionality that the `Series` framework offers. I.e. to show that direct expansion over `1/j` as `j -> 0` is possible. See the comment of @user64494 on the question itself.

Comment: Good point! I’ve just done so.

Comment: @thorimur: Don't truble it.

Answer (score 4):

```
Series[(1 + 1/j)^x/(1 + x/j), {j, Infinity, 2}]
```

$$1+\frac{(x-1) x}{2 j^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^3\right) . $$