# Is there a easy way to make a Taylor Expansion in MMa?

Tags: replacement, series-expansion

We know from special relativity that:$$E^2=m_0^2c^2+p^2c^4$$$$E=\sqrt{m_0^2c^2+p^2c^4}$$$$p=m_0v$$$$E=m_0^2c^2(1+v^2)^{1/2}$$Now I know that I can use a Taylor Series to approximate the square root term when $v\ll c$:$$(1+x)^\alpha=(1+\alpha x)$$So, on paper, I can substitute in $x=v^2$ and $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$, to get this approximation (when $v \ll c$):$$E=m_0^2c^2(1+\frac{1}{2}v^2)$$$$E=m_0^2c^2+\frac{1}{2}m_0^2c^2v^2$$Is there a clever way that I can do employ a Taylor Series in Mathematica to make the estimation for me, or do I just have to substitute by hand?

```
Expand[E /. Sqrt[1 + v^2] -> 1 + 1/2 v^2]
```

Comment: Have you seen [`Series`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html)?

Comment: I have, but I don't know how to employ it in this context.  I was able to get this far by hand:$$Simplify[Expand[Sum[(Derivative[n][f][0]*x^n)/n!, {n, 0, 2}]]]$$But couldn't figure out how to use the output (which appears to be the same form as **Series**) to accomplish the substitution that I needed:$$(1+x)^\alpha->(1+\alpha x)$$

Comment: `ee = m0^2 c^2 Sqrt[1 + v^2]; Series[ee, {v, 0, 2}]`?

Comment: You can do `Normal@Series[..]` to get rid of the big-O term, if you like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "prepare" expression for Taylor expansion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241057/how-to-prepare-expression-for-taylor-expansion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is wrong. It should read (I will write `en` for energy because E is a reserved symbol):

```
en^2= (p c)^2 + (m0 c^2)^2 

en^2= (m0 v c)^2 +(m0 c^2)^2

en= Sqrt[ (m0 v c)^2 +(m0 c^2)^2]
```

We expand en in a series of v around zero and simplify:

```
Simplify[Series[en, {v, 0, 2}], {m0 > 0, c > 0}]
```

[image]