# Get rid of of $O(\epsilon^2) $ terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

So basically I have the expression on the form:

```
(4 ϵ^3 a b )/((-1+ϵ)^2 (a-b)^2)
```

or $ \frac{4 \epsilon^3 ab }{(\epsilon -1)^2 (a-b)^2} $.

I guess this is a math and Mathematica question. I only want to keep orders of $\epsilon^1$. But I don't know how to collect the $O(\epsilon^2)$ terms when I have something like $(\epsilon -1)^2 $ in the denominator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if you want to expand the denominator as a polynomial or a fraction. Here's the latter: `(4 \[Epsilon]^3 a b) Normal@ Series[1/((-1 + \[Epsilon])^2 (a - b)^2), {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "prepare" expression for Taylor expansion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241057/how-to-prepare-expression-for-taylor-expansion)